# HB11 fusion Engine

Tags: fusion, cold-fusion

Looking for a way to achieve torch ship performance (https://www.projectrho.com/public_html/rocket/torchships.php#torchdrive)

Without strapping my reactor/engine to the outside of my ship. The main problems with this appear to be the waste energy turned into heat (non charged neutrons and x/gamma rays) from fusion reactions. As well as the low mass flow rate that gives fusion drives such high specific impulse.

I was wondering if HB11 fusion solved this? https://hb11.energy/

It’s virtually eliminates this waste energy, (but doesn’t totally) which maybe allows me to have a 12 terwatt reactor/engine that doesn’t vaporize itself?

Comment: Hi, welcome to Physics SE. I'm not sure "will this speculative fusion reactor design even provide net power, let alone be safe for space travel?" questions are considered [on-topic](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) here. If you're looking for realistic insights, try Space SE; if you're looking for a story-friendly approach, try Worldbuilding SE. (Either way, check what questions they deem on-topic.)

Comment: Why are you not expecting lots of gammas from the wide range of observed reactions?

Comment: -Jon Custer I am, just orders of magnitude less than say a Helium3 deuterium reaction.

Comment: -J.G. I was actually sent here for Sci Fi stack exchange cause they said my question was more y’all’s speed. 

My question really boils down to, given a net energy gain HB11 fusion reaction by whatever means. Could that be scaled up to 12 terawatts without vaporizing a physical reactor/engine.

Comment: @JonCuster the proton boron reaction happens to be rather low on that. MichaelFerrell they currently have a gain value that is 0.00...